# How to generate a USING clause in JOIN queries with Laravel's Query Builder?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, join, laravel-4

PostgreSQL supports [USING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html) clauses in JOIN statements, and I want to use it to simplify my query. For example:

```
 select * from a join b using (x, y, z) where ... order by x;
```

How do I express this with Laravel's Query Builder or Eloquent?

```
DB::table('a')
    ->select('*')
    ->join('b', function($join))
    ->where(...)
    ->orderBy('x');
```

Note that this question is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465918/how-to-generate-a-natural-join-query-with-laravels-query-builder where I was asking about NATURAL JOIN, not JOIN USING.

Also, I'm aware that I can have almost the same effect with multiple `$join->on(...)` statements, but then I have duplicate columns and must always qualify columns that are in both `a` and `b`. That is, I'd have to write `'a.x'` instead of `'x'` even though it doesn't matter, because the join query ensures that both are equal anyway. The USING clause solves this problem neatly, by generating only a single result column `x`, knowing there is only this one value.

Comment: I guess if you set up your DB tables following the Laravel conventions (having primary keys always named "id"), USING won't be of much use, because it relies on primary and foreign keys having the same name. So it's probably not a high priority for them...

Answer (score 4):

So, the answer is - it's impossible.

I continued this question on Laravel 5, and it's still impossible.

My question - [Laravel 5. Using the USING operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076108/laravel-5-using-the-using-operator)

My pull request - https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/12773

Comment: I would've liked `->joinUsing($table, $column);` better, but ultimately TayTay gonna TayTay and won't allow anything that isn't made by his inner circle of sycophants.