# Laravel 5. Using the USING operator

Tags: php, laravel, join, using

I tried to find it for a long time, and I can't believe that Laravel doesn't have this functionality.

So, I can write:

```
select * from a join b where a.id = b.id
```

or more beautiful:

```
select * from a join b using(id)
```

First case is simple for Laravel:

```
$query->leftJoin('b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.id')
```

But how to write second case? I expect that it should be simple and short, like:

```
$query->joinUsing('b', 'id')
```

But thereis no such method and I can't find it.

PS: it's possible that the answer is very simple, it's just hard to find by word "using", because it's everywhere.

**UPDATE**

I'm going deeper to source, trying to make scope or pass a function to join, but even inside of this function I can't to anything with this $query. Example:

```
public function scopeJoinUsing($query, $table, $field) {
    sql($query->join(\DB::raw("USING(`{$field}`)")));
    // return 
    // inner join `b` on USING(`id`)  ``
    // yes, with "on" and with empty quotes
    sql($query->addSelect(\DB::raw("USING(`{$field}`)")));
    // return 
    // inner join `b` USING(`id`) 
    // but in fields place, before "FROM", which is very logic :)
}
```

So even if forget about scope , I can't do this in DB::raw() , so it's impossible... First time I see that something impossible in Laravel.

Comment: What you want to do exactly by this 'using(id)'. What kind of result you are expecting from query.

Comment: What you are looking for does not exist as far as I understand the documentation and the API. You could make a pull request to include it tho!

Comment: @AlankarMore , I have a big complicated query with SELECT * FROM (SELECT * with JOIN). When I'm making subquery with JOIN ON , in result I have 2 columns with the same name "id". And I have an error "Duplicate columns". 
It's very easy to fix with USING , because it will return only 1 column "id". 
Other option - do not use "table_name.*" in SELECT , but it's too long and wrong, if I can fix it with simple MySQL command.

Comment: @El_Matella , yes, now I understand it. Of course I can fix it and make pull request, but it's a long way. Now I'm looking for some ugly hack, which is work, I will just hide it in some nice scope and it's done.

Comment: do you really need all the fields from the table? If not then you can make alias for the duplicate columns. may you have already tried for this but just a suggestion you can use it like `SELECT table.id as tableId FROM table`.

Answer (score 2):

So, the answer is - it's impossible.

Laravel doesn't support this functionality, which is really sad.

I fix it in Laravel source code, my PULL REQUEST here - https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/12773

Comment: Exactly the question I had - yes, I'm surprised it's not possible